# Group lines from the CSV file

Tags: java, algorithm, csv

I have a CSV file which looks like this:

> ```
> ID | Name | Date
> "1","Foo1","2013-08-03 21:00:08"
> "1","Foo2","2013-08-03 21:00:08"
> "2","Foo3","2013-08-03 21:00:08"
> ...
> ```

I need to write a method which returns a list of the lines with same ID and date, for reading the CSV file I am using OpenCSV. My question is whether or not this method can be rewritten in more elegant way.

```java
private String[] currentWorkerLine;
private String relationIdentifier;
private String currentStartDate;
private int rowCount;

private List<String[]> getWorkers(CSVReader reader) throws Exception{
    List<String[]> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    if (currentWorkerLine == null && rowCount == 0){
        currentWorkerLine = reader.readNext();
        relationIdentifier = currentWorkerLine[0];
        currentStartDate = currentWorkerLine[2];
        workers.add(currentWorkerLine);
        rowCount++;
    }

    while ((currentWorkerline = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        if (!isRelatedLine(currentWorkerline[0]) || !isCurrentDateLine(currentWorkerline[2])){
            lastLine = currentWorkerline;
            return workers;
        }
        relationIdentifier = currentWorkerline[0];
        currentStartDate = currentWorkerline[2];
        workers.add(currentWorkerline);
        lastLine = currentWorkerline;
        rowCount++;
    }
    if (currentWorkerline == null && lastLine != null) {
        workers.add(lastLine);
        rowCount++;
        lastLine = null;
    }
    return workers;
}

private boolean isRelatedLine(String rel) {
    return rel.equals(relationIdentifier);
}

private boolean isCurrentDateLine(String date) {
    return date.equals(currentStartDate);
}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: @h.j.k. yeap I am using Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Class variables

Considering that neither the method nor the list of variables (plus what seems to be a missing `private String[] lastLine`) are `static`, I presume these belong to a class which requires instantiation for it to work.

This approach is fine - without knowing what else the class is doing - but I'm not too sure if `currentWorkerLine` (you have a `currentWorkerline` too, I'm going to assume that's just a small typo) and `lastLine` really needs to be 'saved' as class variables. For example, at the end of the method, is there a need to set `lastLine = null`?

## Throwing `Exception`s

The only checked `Exception` I can see from the method is just [`reader.readNext()`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReader.html#readNext()), so you may want to replace the `throws Exception` part with the stricter `throws IOException`. This forces the method callers to explicitly deal with an I/O-related error, instead of an unusually wide `Exception`, which offers no (direct) hint as to what has gone wrong.

BTW, on a related note, if the code happens to deal with a malformed CSV input, the line `currentWorkerLine = reader.readNext();` will cause `NullPointerException` should `reader.readNext()` return `null`. You may want to check for this, just to be sure.

## Comparisons

While your code block is looping through the lines that have passed the identity check, there is no need to keep re-assigning `relationIdentifier` and `currentStartDate`:

```
while ((currentWorkerline = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (!isRelatedLine(currentWorkerline[0]) || !isCurrentDateLine(currentWorkerline[2])){
        lastLine = currentWorkerline;
        return workers;
    }
    // they will be the same as the past values, so why re-assign?
    //relationIdentifier = currentWorkerline[0];
    //currentStartDate = currentWorkerline[2];
    workers.add(currentWorkerline);
    lastLine = currentWorkerline;
    rowCount++;
}
```

## Model classes

You may also want to consider having a suitable model class to give a better representation to the three-column row inputs you get over the current `String[]`. With a model class, you can have a custom `equals()` implementation that only compares the ID and date values between two 'instances' aka rows, so that the next different row will return `false` for the comparison. This may simplify not only your approach within the method here, but outside usage as well for the method callers to deal with the `List` of results.

Also, food for thought, would it be better/more efficient to return one `Result` object that contains an `id`, `startDate` and a `List<String>` of `names`, since the `id` and `startDate` are the same for all the names?